# How to display a list of elements from a set of data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polaris

I am trying to create a list of products using a set of data in react. I want to return the titles from this data and display it on screen in a list. I am trying to use a `forEach` loop but I'm not sure exactly how to achieve this.

This is what I have so far:

```
import info from "./info";
import React from "react";

const ProductList = () => {
  function listItems(item) {
    return (
      <Listbox.Option>
        <Heading>{node.title}</Heading>
      </Listbox.Option>
    );
  }

  info.data.products.edges.forEach(listItems);

  return listItems();
};

export default ProductList;
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to below:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Test1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Test2"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((x) => {
        return <li key={x.id}>{x.title}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

You can run the code in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-chihiro-vrj0fh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe simplify it so a version that looks like this:

```
import info from "./info";
import React from "react";

const ProductList = () => {
  return info.data.products.edges.map((node) => (
    <Listbox.Option>
      <Heading>{node.title}</Heading>
    </Listbox.Option>
  ));
};

export default ProductList;
```

Would this work for you ?

Comment: The difference from your solution is, this line: 
`info.data.products.edges.forEach(listItems);`

didn't really do anything except for looping over the elements, and since the return value of the forEach callback doesn't do anything, nothing happened

and then you called `listItem()` without passing an argument to it, and it should take one, so you could remove the first line we discussed and then pass the items for your function like: 
`return listItems(info.data.products.edges);`
but then the answer posted above would just look more simplified version of it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would want to use the `map()` method instead of `forEach`, something like this:

```
import info from "./info";
import React from "react";

const ProductList = () => {
  function listItems(item, key) {
    return (
      <Listbox.Option key={key}>
        <Heading>{node.title}</Heading>
      </Listbox.Option>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {info.data.products.edges.map((item, index) => listItems(item, index))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```